# Run Ubuntu Security Updates every Saturday only

Tags: ubuntu, security

A client wants to enable automatic security updates on their 12.04 box, but it has to be once per week, on saturday only (why I don't know).

When I do `dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` it's daily, and they do not want that.

How would I configure this?

Comment: Check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo

Comment: You can move the apt file from `/etc/cron.daily/apt` and run it from a self cron file in `/etc/cron.d`

Answer (score 2):

If it's absolutely important to run only on Saturdays, then do this:

1. Remove the package `anacron`. Note that this also removes `ubuntu-desktop`, but you probably won't need it on a server. This is necessary, because otherwise it's impossible to control on which day of the week Anacron will run the jobs in `/etc/cron.weekly`.
2. Edit the file `/etc/crontab`, it should have the following line:

   ```
   47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
   ```

   Change the `7` to `6` (Saturday) and adjust the first two numbers (minute and hour) to your needs. This will cause all jobs in `/etc/cron.weekly` to run at the specified day of the week and hour.
3. Move the file `/etc/cron.daily/apt` to `/etc/cron.weekly/apt`.

Answer (score 2):

The `apt` file in `/etc/cron.daily` includes instructions for this:

```
# Create /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic file to set your preference.
....
#
#  APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
#  - Run the "unattended-upgrade" security upgrade script
#    every n-days (0=disabled)
#    Requires the package "unattended-upgrades" and will write
#    a log in /var/log/unattended-upgrades
```

setting

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "7";
```

makes this run every seven days, and if you change that on Friday, the first cron daily run will Saturday morning (6:25AM according to the default `/etc/crontab`).

If the machine is down at that time, the script will run on the following day that the system is up. And every week after that (new) day. That way you get weekly updates on a machine that is not always up on a given day, but not what you want.

One thing you can do about getting out of sync is using a crontab entry to run a touch command that touches the stamp file `/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-stamp` appropriately (ie. sets it to 'done last saturdaymorning')

Comment: This is very brittle. If after setting this, there is downtime on a Saturday so that the cron.daily script doesn't execute, the upgrades will start happening on a different day of the week.

Comment: @KrzysztofKosiński You are mistaken, what happens is that it runs on Sunday when the machine is up again (or any other day this happens). It gets out of sync running on that day following that until manual intervention. Annoying enough, but calling it brittle is inappropriate, that would happen if you schedule the update fixed time every Saturday

Comment: If it's more important to run on Saturdays only than to run at least once every N days, then anything using anacron is not adequate. It's not immediately clear what the OP's client wants.